# Read multiple file contents from S3 bucket and look for a keyword

Tags: python

I have an S3 folder which has folders and each folder has 1000 json objects. I don't want to return all the contents of those 1000 files, I just need to read those 1000 files and check if one keyword is present in any of the files and return the filename if that particular keyword is present.

```
s3sr = boto3.client('s3')

def fetch_files_from_AWS_S3(bucket,prefix):
   #gets list of keys for given bucket and prefix'''
     Keys_list = []
     paginator = s3sr.meta.client.get_paginator('list_objects')
     # use Delimiter to limit search to that level of hierarchy
     for page in paginator.paginate(Bucket=AWS_s3bucket,Prefix=prefix, Delimiter='/'):
         keys = [content['Key'] for content in page.get('Contents')]
          print('keys in page: ', len(keys))
           keys_list.extend(keys)
     return keys_list

def s3_file_read(self,source):
    AWS_s3bucket = ''
    region=''
     prefix = 's3-bucket-folder-name/' 

    ACCESS_KEY_ID = ''
    ACCESS_SECRET_KEY = ''
    s3_client =                  boto3.client('s3',aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY_ID,aws_secret_access_key=ACCESS_SECRET_KEY,region_name=region) 

     keys_list = self.get_keys_from_prefix(bucket_name, prefix)
```

I am not understanding how to proceed with next step of reading those 1000 of files to search for that one keyword

Comment: @Mrflick I have to read those files and look for one specific keyword if it is present in any of those files or not

Comment: If you need to do this once, fine. If you need to do this regularly: this'll take quite a bit of time and won't be a very good approach.

Comment: I just need to do this once @deceze